# Pan gesture in UITableViewCell that can move image view all over tableview without going beneath the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, pan

I am trying to create a tinder like swipe left and right in UITableView cell. Here, the tableview cell contains an image view which I can move around with pan gesture. When I initiate the gesture on the image view, I want to move it freely over my device screen.

I am facing the problem that when I move the image view around it goes below the current cell. How can I bring the image view over all others so it doesn't go below the cell frame?

I tried using `view.bringSubviewToFront` but it doesn't work.

Please suggest a way I can achieve this.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code, as text.

Comment: Please share code for better understanding and checking what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

An image view still contained in a cell is not going to be reliably brought on top of all other relevant views. You will have to move that view from the cell to the table view's parent view while dragging (and then return it to the cell if necessary at the end).

You will probably want to look into `UIView.convert(_:from:)` to figure out the frame to move the image view to in the parent view.